# Error deploying Mule application in mule standalone

Tags: mule

I have created a mule application and it's running well in anypoint studio when i run it with mule 3.5.6 CE but when i try to deploy it in mule-standalone-3.6.1 i get this:

```
 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    + New app 'pushv1'                                         +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    INFO  2015-03-30 10:56:03,009 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
    ncher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'pushv1' never started, nothing to
     dispose of
    ERROR 2015-03-30 10:56:03,010 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
    ncher.DefaultArchiveDeployer:
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    + Failed to deploy artifact 'pushv1', see below            +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    org.mule.module.launcher.InstallException: Config for app 'pushv1' not found: C:
    \mule-standalone-3.6.1\apps\pushv1\mule-config.xml
            at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.install(D
    efaultMuleApplication.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$3.execute(ArtifactW
    rapper.java:74) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifa
    ctClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.install(ArtifactWra
    pper.java:69) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifa
    ctDeployer.java:24) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(Default
    ArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(Defaul
    tArchiveDeployer.java:330) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(Def
    aultArchiveDeployer.java:297) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifac
    t(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApp
    s(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentD
    irectoryWatcher.java:151) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentSe
    rvice.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0
    _40]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0
    _40]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1
    .8.0_40]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
            at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrappe
    r.java:52) ~[mule-module-reboot-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
            at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:
    2788) ~[wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    INFO  2015-03-30 10:56:03,012 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
    ncher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher:
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    + Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    INFO  2015-03-30 10:56:03,033 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.mo
    dule.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: ================== Request to Undeploy Art
    ifact: pushv1
    INFO  2015-03-30 10:56:03,035 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.mo
    dule.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'pushv1' never started, no
    thing to dispose of
    ERROR 2015-03-30 10:56:03,040 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.lau
    ncher.MuleDeploymentService: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can someone help me please. thank you in advance

Comment: how did you create the deployable folder? from anypoint studio?

Comment: yes. i had created the application to deploy in anypoint studio and it's running well with the embedded server 3.5.0 CE.

Comment: Check in your application if there is mule-config.xml written in mule-deploy.properties ... if there is , then change remove it from there

Comment: This is the content of my mule-deploy.properties: #** GENERATED CONTENT ** Mule Application Deployment Descriptor
#Sun Mar 29 14:59:25 WEST 2015
redeployment.enabled=true
encoding=UTF-8
domain=default
config.resources=pushv1.xml

Comment: Which version standalone are you deploying and getting this issue and also which version standalone is it working fine ???

Comment: in anypoint studio the application is running with mule server 3.5.0 CE. and the external server that i had installed and where i want to deploy my application is: mule-standalone-3.6.1

Comment: My concern is why this mule-config.xml is coming between ? do you have this file in your application ??

Comment: All files that i have is pushv1.xml, mule-app.properties (wich is empty), mule-deploy.properties and finaly mule-project.xml

Comment: You created the deployable zip file for your app through the export option in AnypointStudio? 
Keep in mind that there were lots of changes between 3.5.0 and 3.6.1, I would suggest trying in 3.5.0 standalone and downloading the latest Anypoint Studio Runtime to create future apps if you will be deploying to 3.6.1.

Comment: I have tested with 3.5.0 standalone and the error i get is: http://pastebin.com/vM0V1T2B

Comment: Please deploy zip file from your studio .. Select your apllication, then Go to file menu --> export --> under Mule folder -->select Anypoint studio to Mule deployable archieve --> give the name .. it will generate a Zip file  .. Deploy that zip file in your app folder of standalone .. that's the way .. don't create any zip from winzip or other tools

Comment: yeahhh, thank you everybody and specially Mr @AnirbanSenChowdhary your answer helped me.

Comment: I have written in the answer section .. pls accept the answer .. It might help other people learning Mule

Comment: yes of course with pleasure, thank you again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please deploy zip file from your studio .. Select your apllication, then Go to file menu --> export --> under Mule folder -->select Anypoint studio to Mule deployable archieve --> give the name .. it will generate a Zip file .. Deploy that zip file in your app folder of standalone .. that's the way .. don't create any zip from winzip or other tools

Comment: The other option is use maven.  You'll have to download that, install it, configure it in Studio and then generate a POM file.  All the instructions for that process can be found at mulesoft.org

Answer (score 2):

When you run your mule application from Anypoint Studio, it runs on mule embedded server, so you were able to run the application properly. To run your application on standalone please make sure below thing apart from other suggestions:

- Is the version of standalone server same as the server you have selected during creating a mule application.

It's always good to have a maven project. You can mavenize your normal project by right clicking and selecting option mavenize in anypoint studio.

once mavenize it starts building and installing dependency. It can be seen in your console. Finally, you will get **Build Success** message.

Now go to the target folder and you will get a zip of your project. Just pick it and paste it inside **apps** folder of standalone.

Answer (score 1):

Its nothing to do with version. I think its the problem with the way of deployment (As Anirban told deploy the zip file in you app foldeer)

Answer (score 1):

You should create maven based mule project and use maven for generating zip file . 
pom.xml should contain the version of mule to use. Deploy the zip generated in mule standalone and run with mule start.

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing you need to check is do you have this xml file in mule-deploy.properties file.
2. If not add this file name and try to run it again.Try to import your application as Zip file and deploy it to cloudhub and try it.